# Break and explain function codes. TQ

Tags: python, function, lambda, parentheses

Break and explain function codes  . ......................................................................................

```
 def checkio(text): 
         return (lambda x: max(x, key=x.count))(sorted([i for i in text.lower() if i.isalpha()]))
```

1. Can someone break this into normal form pls?
2. What are these parentheses mean (........ )(.........)?

I already know the output of this program just that I don't know how this works.

Thank You.

Comment: You define and immediately call a `lambda`. Instead, you can just define `x = sorted...` in a separate statement. Or better: Use `collections.Counter.most_common`.

Answer (score 0):

With the `(...)(...)` you define and immediately call a `lambda` and pass it the `sorted` list as the parameter `x`. The first `(...)` is for operator precedence (call the `lambda`, not the result of `max`), the second `(...)` is regular function call syntax. It's clearer if you move the lambda to a separate line:

```
def checkio(text):
    f = lambda x: max(x, key=x.count)
    return f(sorted([i for i in text.lower() if i.isalpha()]))
```

It's even more clearer, if you drop the lambda and instead just define the list as `x` and call `max` directly. Also, no need to sort the list.

```
def checkio(text):
    x = [i for i in text.lower() if i.isalpha()]
    return max(x, key=x.count)
```

This is still pretty inefficient, though, as the repeated calls to `count` make it O(n²). Better use `collections.Counter` to count all at once, then get the `most_common` element.

```
from collections import Counter
def checkio(text):
    return Counter(i for i in text.lower() if i.isalpha()).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Comment: Addendum: Actually, the `sorted` _does_ make a difference: Acting as a tie-breaker in case two chars appear equally often, but it would be cleaner to use `max` with a `key` that returns a tuple instead.

Answer (score 0):

well this function is giving the alphabet character having maximum occuerance.

so insort this function is like this

```
def checkio(text):

    if len(text) == 0:
          return None

    def get_alphabets(text):
        return [char for char in text.lower() if char.isapha()]

    def get_most_frequent(array):
        result = {}
        for char in array:
            if char not in result:
                 result[char] = 0
            result[char] += 1
        max_occu = max(result.values)
        max_occurernce_char = [ char for char, value in result.items() if value == max_occu]
        returm max_occuerence_char
    
    clean_alphabets_in_lower = get_alphabets(text)
    max_occuernce_chars = get_most_frequent(clean_alphabets_in_lower)
    
    return max_occuernce_chars
```